# useSearchParams Typescript helper to desctructure search parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to extend useSearchParams to be strongly typed so that I can destructure the search parameters, instead of accessing each parameter by `ULRSearchParameter.get('some-search-parameter')`.

```
const [{ hello, foo }, setSearchParams] = useTypedSearchParams<{
hello: string;
foo: string;
}>();
```

Ideally, I would like `setSearchParams` to be typed as well.

`setSearchParams({ notvalid: '' });` would show as an error.

`setSearchParams({ foo: 'bud', hello: 'zombie });` would not.

I have a working implementation but have a typing issue.
Below is a sample of the hook, and of course, a working [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-noyce-xr7tr2?file=/src/useTypedSearchParams.ts).

```
export const useTypedSearchParams = <T>(
  defaultInit?: URLSearchParamsInit | undefined
) => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams(defaultInit);

  type ParamType = Partial<Record<keyof T, string>>;
  let params: ParamType = {};

  for (const [key, value] of searchParams.entries()) {
    params[key] = value;
  }

  return [{ ...params }, setSearchParams] as const;
};
```